# wp_new_comment requires author url and author email

Tags: comments, notices

I am using the `wp_new_comment()` (previously used the `wp_insert_comment()`) function.

I now notice that I get a

> Notice: Undefined index: comment_author_url

and a:

> Notice: Undefined index: comment_author_email

in the `wp-includes/comment.php` file.

Previously, when using `wp_insert_comment()` I left these fields in the arguments blank (ie: left them out of the arguments array) and I didn't receive any notices.

How come I am receiving a notice for these arguments now? Are these arguments required for the `wp_new_comment()` function but not for `wp_insert_comment()`? If so, why?

All of my comments are written by registered users. I can simply enter empty strings for these fields or use the user's registration information to populate the fields. Any suggestions regarding this?

(my comment form is taken from the plugin I'm using).

Thanks.

Comment: How are you including your code when you write I'm using ? wp_new_comment need 1 argument. your array of data doesn't seems to be populated.

Comment: I did not show any array of data, but it doesn't have `comment_author_url` nor `comment_author_email`. It has comment_post_ID, comment_content, comment_parent, comment_type, user_id, comment_author.

Answer (score 1):

The example from the codex, the array of argument is now required.

```
global $post, $current_user; //for this example only :)

    $commentdata = array('comment_post_ID' => $post->ID, // to which post the comment will show up
        'comment_author' => 'Another Someone', //fixed value - can be dynamic 
        'comment_author_email' => 'someone@example.com', //fixed value - can be dynamic 
        'comment_author_url' => 'http://example.com', //fixed value - can be dynamic 
        'comment_content' => 'Comment messsage...', //fixed value - can be dynamic 
        'comment_type' => '', //empty for regular comments, 'pingback' for pingbacks, 'trackback' for trackbacks
        'comment_parent' => 0, //0 if it's not a reply to another comment; if it's a reply, mention the parent comment ID here
        'user_id' => $current_user->ID, //passing current user ID or any predefined as per the demand
   );

  //Insert new comment and get the comment ID
  $comment_id = wp_new_comment( $commentdata );
```

You can have a look to wp_filter_comment(), the source shows some filters that set fill $commentdata. Maybe one of these are used by the plugin you use.

Comment: Hello and thanks. Where in the codex does it say that comment_author_email and comment_author_url are required?

Comment: The array is required, the value of the key comment_author_url can be empty.